# PhotoBucket Integration

Tags: iphone

could anyone assist in authenticating to photobucket and uploading an image from and iPhone app? I am currently configured with many networks but I can't really find good documentation for the photobucket process. What are the basic steps to integrate photo bucket ?

Any help here would be amazing! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: http://photobucket.com/developer/forum?list,3
I think from all of those sample codes you can get some useful info for your app.
It will be useful to start from registering to http://photobucket.com/developer/

Comment: i got Photobucket API sample code.it is not running.i mean its showing me Build Successfully but not running on simulator.

Comment: Actually I have never worked with it so I can't tell you what the problem is. Try searching that forum for info, maby try to ask for help there. Sorry, but these links were everything I could help you in this problem. By the way, try your app on iPhone, because simulators sometimes are not working as real device